# pandas writing to a subset based on condition till end of the group category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below and the expected output column is 'check':

```
Country Temp    check
0   Canada  25  0.0
1   Canada  26  0.0
2   Canada  27  1.0
3   Canada  25  1.0
4   Canada  24  1.0
5   USA 25  0.0
6   USA 26  0.0
7   USA 27  1.0
8   USA 23  1.0
9   USA 22  1.0
```

The check column turns one when the temperature exceeds 26 degrees and remains 1 till the country changes. I did this with a loop:

```
check = 0
country_old = ''
for r in range(len(df)):
  country_new = df.iloc[r]['Country']
  if country_new!=country_old:
    check = 0
    country_old = country_new
  if df.iloc[r]['Temp']>26:
    check = 1
  df.loc[r,'check'] = check
```

But is too slow for my dataframe (200k+ rows). is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: The column 'check' is the expected output column.

Comment: @AdnanHadi Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby.transform` with `gt` and `cumsum`:

```
>>> df['check'] = df.groupby('Country')['Temp'].transform(lambda x: x.gt(26).cumsum())
>>> df
  Country  Temp  check
0  Canada    25      0
1  Canada    26      0
2  Canada    27      1
3  Canada    25      1
4  Canada    24      1
5     USA    25      0
6     USA    26      0
7     USA    27      1
8     USA    23      1
9     USA    22      1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cumsum() from @U12-Forward will return 0,0,1,2,3. I suggest using astype('int') to convert T/F value into 0/1.

```
df['check'] = df.groupby('Country')['Temp'].transform(lambda x: x.gt(26).astype('int'))
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected output as the 1's do not continue to the end of the group as required.